# Is it a bad idea to use a Pozidriv screwdriver on a Phillips head?

Tags: screw, phillips

Most DIY-ers will have experienced the frustration of self-inflicted screw damage due to the use of the wrong screwdriver type (or size, but let's keep that factor out of this particular question).

My [research thus far](https://web.archive.org/web/20180615174742/http://justbrits.com/pozi/pozidriv.html) indicates that the key difference between Phillips and Pozidriv screwdrivers is the fact that Phillips drivers are designed to "torque out" of the screw head if over-torqued, which increases the likelihood of material damage and distortion to both screw head and driver. Pozidriv, on the other hand, is designed such that it cannot jump out if over-torqued.

The same source mentions the both screwdriver and head should be of the same type:

> Phillips drivers should not be used with Posidriv screws (and vice
>   versa) as they tend to ride out of the recess and round the corners of
>   both the tool and screw recess.

While I can understand this for the Phillips screwdriver on a Pozidriv head, I struggle to see why this would be an issue for the reverse combination, since the risk of torque-out is absent and the screw head groove geometry appears to be quite similar.

Here is a side-by-side comparison of the two driver types (Phillips left, Pozidriv right):

[image: Phillips vs. Pozidriv]

Comment: It looks like there are some significant differences in the design. http://s1212.photobucket.com/user/rsn-mk1/media/rsn%20blog/screwdrivers.jpg.html

Comment: I have been using a hand held Stanley No.1 Pozidriv screwdriver on various size Phillips head screws for years now and found that it works very well, in fact better and tighter than a Phillips screwdriver in some cases..

Answer (score 13):

The Pozidriv screw is an advanced version of the Phillips screw but the key difference is that:

- Phillips drivers have an intentional angle on the flanks and rounded
  corners so they will cam out of the slot before a power tool will
  twist off the screw head. The Pozidriv screws and drivers have
  straight sided flanks.
- Each of the arms of the cross are parallel-sided on
  the Pozidriv, but they are tapered off with the Phillips. (refer the below image, look at the 45° notch between the arms)

  [image: Ignore the spelling mistake on Pozidriv]

> This design is intended to decrease the likelihood that the Pozidriv
> screwdriver will cam out, providing a greater driving surface, and
> decrease wear

As you state , Phillips screwdrivers will fit in and turn Pozidriv screws, but will cam out if enough torque is applied, and can damage the screw head.

BUT.

The marker lines on a Pozidriv screwdriver will not fit a Phillips screw correctly, and are likely to tear out or warp the screw head. Slippage is also possible, if the screw is relativity new and not subjected to corrosion.

Meaning, if you use a Phillips on a Pozidriv you have greater chances of slippage.

But if you use a Pozidriv on a Phillips it will shred the screw head and slippage is always better than destroying the screw thus, so you can at least try the former if you have no proper tool kit.

The above is the only main disadvantage of the Pozidriv head , its very similar to look as the Phillips and unaware users end up with damaged/warped screw head.